# Thousands separators when printing summary in R

Tags: r, formatting

Sometimes when printing the summary of a data frame it is difficult to quickly compare columns because there are no thousands separators. `summary()` accepts a parameter named `digits` that can be used to tweak a little bit the output. But still, without thousands separators it is not easy to compare columns in many cases.

Is there any way to alter the output of a summary information in order to add thousands separators? Perhaps some command that post-process the output of `summary`?

Comment: I know of `prettyNum`, e.g. `prettyNum(x, big.mark = ",")` will insert a comma at thousands, however, the returned vector is a character (not numeric). Thus, the classical summary won't work, it just counts the unique "strings": `summary(apply(WorldPhones, 2, function(x) if (max(x, na.rm = T) > 999) prettyNum(x, big.mark = ",") else x))`.

Comment: @Daniel, why not just use `prettyNum` on the output of `summary`: `prettyNum(summary(x),big.mark=",")`? I may be a bit confused about what exactly OP is looking for, but at least this gets around the initial-conversion-to-strings problem

Comment: Indeed, swapping position of summary and prettyNum does the trick!

Comment: @MichaelChirico Unfortunately using prettyNum does not work for all the fields. Thousands separators work correctly for fields such as "mean" and "median". But they do not for others such as "minimum/maximum" or "1st/3rd quartiles". I'm not familiar with prettyNum, but it might be the case it gets fooled by the dot after "Min", "Max", etc.

Comment: Interesting, that's unfortunate. You'd have to go into the source code of `summary` to use `prettyNum` just before it pastes in the summary numbers for printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of that feature. However, for nicely formatted summary statistics (and output of models, too) you might find packages `stargazer`, `sjPlot` and the like useful which have that feature.

Comment: Daniel's answer is more comprehensive, so I suggest to accept his answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a `big.marks` parameter to the `sjt.df` function of my sjPlot-package, see latest [GitHub-build](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel). This function uses the `describe` function of the `psych` package and puts the output into a formatted HTML-table.

```
sjt.df(as.data.frame(WorldPhones), big.mark = ",")
```

[image]

or

```
sjt.df(as.data.frame(WorldPhones), 
       big.mark = ",", 
       alternateRowColors = T)
```

[image]

Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: I am getting this one : Error in sjt.df(as.data.frame(WorldPhones), big.mark = ",", alternateRowColors = T) : 
  could not find function "sjt.df

Comment: Meanwhile, this function is re-implemented in the [sjmisc-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjmisc/), called [`descr()`](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjmisc/reference/descr.html). There is an `out`-argument that let's you create HTML tables.